# How can I recover system files damage when sfc isn't working?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption, sfc

I have a lot of electricity outage in my area. It caused disk damage which lead to system files loss.

I've run Chkdsk and here's the results of the recent checks: [CHKDSKResults.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wRqgqQ3PVKVk5rLVkweV90Y2c/edit?usp=sharing).

I've run sfc /scannow and it gives me this message as a result:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing scenarios.
```

Here's the mentioned file: [CBS.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wRqgqQ3PVKQy1pak9hVFZ1cGM/edit?usp=sharing).

My operating system is Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64-bit.

How can I fix my system files in this case knowing that I don't have any backup images or restore points?

Answer (score 1):

A file of inbox driver fro Canon printers can't be repaired:

```
2014-09-23 06:25:37, Info                  CSI    00000816 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-09-23 06:25:37, Info                  CSI    00000818 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"msxactps.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Microsoft-Data-Access-Components-(MDAC)-Oledb-Interface-Remoting-XACTPS, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-09-23 06:25:38, Info                  CSI    0000081a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-09-23 06:25:38, Info                  CSI    0000081c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"msxactps.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Microsoft-Data-Access-Components-(MDAC)-Oledb-Interface-Remoting-XACTPS, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-09-23 06:25:38, Info                  CSI    0000081f [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:106{53}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB"\[l:24{12}]"msxactps.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

This is a bug which Microsoft currently investigates. To repair the corrupted file run [a new DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) which downloads the corrupted files from the internet:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```